# How to solve equations having absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

What is the procedure to solve equations that have multiple expression in absolute values?

Are there popular methods to solve them?

I recently learned, $$|x|≠ ± x $$

So I'm confused as to how does one solve equation that has multiple expression in absolute values like

$$|3x+4| +|2x-1| - \frac{1}{4} |x+5| = 5$$

– Thanks :)

Comment: By considering cases.  Example $|x|=x$ if $x \ge 0$  and $|x|=-x$ if $x<0$..

Comment: @randomgirl Ya I get that, it's easy if you have only one absolute value, but what if you have many of those. Like in the latter example. How would you make cases for that? :o

Comment: I would draw a number line to help me pick the cases.  First find when inside of the absolute values are zero.

Comment: case 1: $x>.5$ , case 2: $\frac{-4}{3}<x<.5$, case 3: $-5<x<\frac{-4}{3}$, and case 4: $x<-5$... Also consider all endpoints as a separate case too.

Comment: I'm just doing comments today because on cell phone.  But consider case 1 with me.  If $x>.5$ then you have all insides are positive

Comment: Yo yo yo hold on! How did you come up with those, I'm not looking for a solution to this. I'm here to learn the method of solving such eqns

Comment: The number line and the zero thing I mentioned

Comment: See my answer for that @William. We are finding when the expression in each mod sign is zero then using that to know when it is positive or negative.

Comment: @William did you draw the number line and plot the 3 numbers on that number line that come from inside of absolute values being zero?

Answer (score 2):

In the range $x<-5$ (note that when $x=-5, x+5=0$), we have 
$$|neg|+|neg|-\frac14|neg|=5$$ as all three expressions within the mod signs are negative in that range.

Thus we can solve:
$$-(3x+4)-(2x-1)+\frac14(x+5)=5$$
and see that $x=-\frac{27}{19}\not<-5$ and therefore in this range there are no solutions.

---

In the range $-5<x<-\frac43$ (note that when $x=-\frac43, 3x+4=0$), we have $$|neg|+|neg|-\frac14|pos|=5$$
So we solve in the range $-5<x<-\frac43$: $$-(3x+4)-(2x-1)-\frac14(x+5)=5$$
and achieve $x=-\frac{37}{21}$ which IS in the correct range and therefore a solution.

Can you continue this?

Comment: For $\frac{-4}{3} < x < \frac{1}{2} $ we have |+ve| + | -ve| - 1/4 |+ve|. On solving I get $x= \frac{13}{19}$ which is a solution! Am I doing this right ? :)

Comment: Be careful. $\frac{13}{19}>\frac12$ so it isn't in the range and thus not a solution.

Comment: Guess I should've just divided to see that :3 I guessed it but at least I got the method right... Right?

Comment: Yes, method looks fine :)

Comment: Ironically, $x=\frac{13}{19}$ is indeed a solution because it also comes out as the answer in the range $x>\frac12$, a range it is in.

Comment: O ffs! Who said I'm ever wrong lol thanks for everything thou :)

Answer (score 2):

To say "$|x| \ne \pm x$" is a little weird.

The problem isn't whether it is true or not but that what it actually *means* is not clear.

$|x| = x$ if $ x \ge 0$.  And $|x| = -x$ if $x \le 0$.  So it *is* true that $|x| =x$ or that $|x| = -x$.

But what does $ \pm x$ mean? First off, there is no *single* number that is $\pm x$.  It's not like Schrodenger's cat, that there is some number that is both $x$ and also $-x$ both at the same time.  I'd say $\pm x$ is simply shorthand for "we want to use one of the values of $x$ or of $-x$ but either we aren't sure which one or in general our result will apply to either so we won't distinguish which".

In that sense, I, personally, interpret a statemen $k = \pm x$ to mean "either $k = x$ or $k = -x$".  Or alternatively I might take it to mean "$\pm x$ is the group of $\{x,-x\}$ and $k$ is one of those members: i.e. '$k=\pm x$' means '$k \in \{x, -x\}$".

So to *me*.  I'd so $|x| = \pm x$ but not the Schrondenger cat superimposed single value idea but that eithe $|x| = x$ or $x= -x$.

....

So to do equations.  I do cases:  Case 1: $|x| = x$ and $x \ge 0$ and Case 2: $|x|= -x$ and $x < 0$.

For example:

$|3x+4| +|2x-1| - \frac{1}{4} |x+5| = 5$

$|3x+4| = \pm(3x + 4); |2x-1|=\pm (2x-1); |x+5| = \pm 5$.  There are three chooses each with two options.  That means there are $2^3 = 8$ cases.

That may seem like a lot but that is okay.  Some of them will be self contradictory and some will be redundent.

Case 1:

$|3x + 4| = 3x+4$ because $3x + 4 \ge 0$ and $|2x-1| = 2x -1$ because $2x -1 \ge 0$ and $|x+5| = x+5$ because $x + 5 \ge 0$.

Now before I even start I want to clear up my conditions for this case.

$3x + 4 \ge 0$ so $x \ge \frac 43$.  And $2x -1 \ge 0$ so $x \ge \frac 12$.  And $x+5 \ge 0$ so $x \ge -5$.  These are redundant.  It is enough to simply say $x \ge \frac 12$.

Now to do it.

$|3x+4| +|2x-1| - \frac{1}{4} |x+5| = 5$

$(3x+4) + (2x-1) -\frac 14(x + 5) = 5$

$5x +3 - \frac x4 - \frac 54 = 5$

$\frac {19}{4}x + \frac 74 = 5$

$19x + 7 = 20$

$19x = 13$

$x = \frac {13}{19}$.

Now I must check does this agree with my assumption that $x \ge \frac 12$.  Yes it does.

$x = \frac {13}{19}$ is one possible answer..

Case 2:

$|3x + 4| = 3x+4$ because $3x + 4 \ge 0$ and $|2x-1| = 2x -1$ because $2x -1 \ge 0$ and $|x+5| = -(x+5)$ because $x + 5 < 0$.

First check our assumptions.  As above: $x \ge -\frac 43$ and $x\ge \frac 15$ *!!BUT!!!*  $x + 5 < 0 \immplies x < -5$.  This is a contradiction.  Case 2 is impossible.

Case 3:  $|3x + 4| = 3x + 4$ and $x \ge -\frac 43$ and $|2x -1| =-(2x-1)$ and $x < \frac 12$ and $|x+5|=x+5$ and $x \ge -5$. In other words $-\frac 43 \le x < \frac 12$

Then

$|3x+4| +|2x-1| - \frac{1}{4} |x+5| = 5$

$(3x+4) - (2x-1) -\frac 14(x + 5) = 5$

$x + 5 -\frac 14(x+5) = 5$

$\frac 34(x+5) = 5$

$x + 5 = \frac {20}3$

$x = \frac 53$

But this contradicts $x < \frac 12$.  So Case 3: is impossible.

Case 4:  $|3x+4|=3x +4$ so $x \ge -\frac43$ and $2x-1 =-(2x-1)$ so $x < \frac 12$ and $|x+5|=-(x+5)$ so $x < -5$.  This is impossible.

Case 5 & 6: $|3x+4| = -(3x + 4)$ so $x < -\frac43$ and $2x-1=2x + 1$ so $x \ge 12$.  That's impossible.

Case 7: $|3x+4| = -(x+4)$ so $x < -\frac 43$ and $2x-1=-(2x +1)$ so $x < \frac 12$ and $|x+5|= x+5$ so $x \ge -5$.  In other words $-5 \le x <-\frac 34$

Then

$|3x+4| +|2x-1| - \frac{1}{4} |x+5| = 5$

$-(3x+4) - (2x-1) -\frac 14(x + 5) = 5$

$-5x - 3 -\frac 14 x -\frac 14 5= -\frac {21x}4 - \frac {17}4 = 5$

$-21x - 17 = 20$

$-21x = 3$

$x =-\frac 3{21}$. But this contradicts $x  < -\frac 43$

Case 8: $|3x+4| = -(x+4)$ so $x < -\frac 43$ and $2x-1=-(2x +1)$ so $x < \frac 12$ and $|x+5|= -(x+5)$ so $x < -5$. In other words $x < -5$.

Then

$|3x+4| +|2x-1| - \frac{1}{4} |x+5| = 5$

$-(3x+4) - (2x-1) +\frac 14(x + 5) = 5$

$-\frac {19}{4}x - \frac 74 = 5$

$-19x - 7 = 20$

$-19x = 27$

$x = -\frac {27}{19}$

This contradicticts $x < -5$.

So the ONLY solution is: $\frac {13}{19}$

Now notice *half* those cases were contradictory from the get-go.

Had we been efficient we would have noticed that:

$|3x +4| = \pm (3x+4)$ or $x \ge;< \frac 43$ and $|2x -1| = \pm(2x + 1)$ or $x \ge;< \frac 12$ and $|x+5|=\pm (x+5)$ or $x \ge;< -5$ center around three *DEPENDENT* critical points: $\frac 12, -\frac 43, -5 $ and these 8 cases break down to an actual four cases:

Case A:  $x \ge \frac 12$

Case B:  $-\frac 43 \le x < \frac 12$

Case C: $-5\le x < -\frac 43$

Dase D: $-5 < x$.

Comment: I stated the above in my answer but not in this detail. I thought it was just busy work but now I see it is good for the questioner to see the reasoning that I omitted.

Answer (score 1):

First, note the definition: $$|f(x)| = f(x) \ \ \ \ \text{if   }\ \ \ \ f(x)\ge0\\|f(x)| = -f(x) \ \text{otherwise}$$
This, in very simple terms, means that any solution to $|f(x)| =$ something is either a solution to $f(x) =$ something, or a solution to  $-f(x) =$ something.

so, for instance, in your case, you have:
$$|f(x)|+|g(x)|-|h(x)|=5\\f(x)=3x+4\\g(x)=2x−1\\h(x)=\frac{x+5}{4}$$

A solution to this equation must also be a solution to one of these:
$$f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=5\\f(x)+g(x)−h(x)=5\\f(x)-g(x)+h(x)=5\\f(x)-g(x)−h(x)=5\\-f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=5\\-f(x)+g(x)-h(x)=5\\-f(x)-g(x)+h(x)=5\\-f(x)-g(x)−h(x)=5$$

It is simple enough to find all of the solutions to each of these, and then check to see if each of these is a solution to the original equation (they may not be, but every solution to the original will be a solution to at least one of these, so you wont miss any). This requires a fair amount of work, and you can be cleverer than this, but I find this to be the most intuitive approach.

To reiterate, any time I have |f(x)| in an equation, I can find the solutions to the equation with |f(x)| replaced with f(x) and the equation with |f(x)| replaced with -f(x), and simply check those values to see if they are solutions in the equation with |f(x)|.

---

If you wish to delve a little bit deeper, you might notice that we do not have to check the solution against the original equation, but merely check that the solution lies in the set where the equations themselves are equal, this means solving the inequalities $$f(x) \ge 0 \\g(x)\ge 0 \\ h(x) \ge 0 \\f(x) \le 0 \\g(x)\le 0 \\ h(x) \le 0$$ we can then associate each of the set of 8 functions we created earlier with the set that satisfies the corresponding collection of inequalities. This would help us, for instance, in the case where, instead of solving $|f(x)|+|g(x)|-|h(x)|=5$ we were solving $|f(x)|+|g(x)|-|h(x)|>5$, where we have infinitely many solutions, and the only way to express them is as the intersection of the sets satisfying each condition separately.